# appengine or aws for apache camel routing

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, routes, apache-camel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First question here so go easy on me.

The producer and endpoints can be sockets/websockets/http(s). These requests will then be processed and sent to subscribed consumers or sent to a queue and routed based on message priority and/or user skill. I would also like to store all the messages and transactions and have options to retry and schedule them.

I know appengine does not support sockets right now, buts its available to trusted testers as of sdk 1.7.5 so that might work in future. This application will not be serving the client pages so the channel api won't work and i don't see any websocket server support, i can work around that i suppose.

On the other hand if i use ec2 then all of those issues go away, but i'll need to scale the application myself, and i'll have to manager the database. I know AWS has other options like SQS, SNS, Beanstalk and simpleDB that could handle the queues, notifications and scaling.

I want to use appengine as it seems like the easier platform to develop for. I know i am not the first person to try to build something like this so i wanted to find out what your experiences were.

Does camel work well with appengine? I know a lot of camel components use threads, jms, jndi which dont work on appengine, were you successful on still using camel on appengine without these. And from my description of what i want the app to do is it possible on appengine or am i better of using ec2. Also has anyone tried doing this with AWS beanstalk.

I have spent a decent amount of time googling around but could not find anything concrete. I have the sample camel app running on appengine, so i know camel works, Just want to make sure the other features i talked about will too. I am new to camel and just learning so sorry if the answer is already obvious or if the questions are vague, any help is appreciated.

Thanks for any insight here!